# Project Considerations: From POC to Consumer product

Tags: production, internet

I come to you for advice. I am a software engineer with some background in electronics, since I studied mechatronics engineering. However I would say that my experience with electronic projects has been more on university stuff, using protoboards and proof-of concept circuits.

Now, I have in mind to combine these two areas in order to develop an IoT solution by creating a project that can perform some simple measurements on office spaces (humidity, temperature), offer dashboards, alerts, and so on.

Now, since most of my experience comes from software development I think of this project to use some principles of Scrum methodology, i.e. to deliver value to the clients as fast as possible. The roadmap that I envision is as follows:

- Start as a simple project that uses some hobbyists components such as ESP32, MQ135 sensors for CO2, BME280 for temperature, etc. These will be mounted on protoboards, and will serve to validate communication to our IoT Hub, dashboards, reporting, communication and so on
- Once this proof of concept has been validated, I will try to move these components to a more permanent setup, i.e. design casing for individual sensors, mount them into a proper soldered board, install them on my office and run them for a couple of months. Fix issues and identify possible extra functionality

Now until this point I feel pretty confident, since even though the project would still be in somewhat a proof of concept phase, it would be running in-house so any issues can be identified and solved efficiently.

Moving forward is what makes me nervous since I identify the following issues

- Replicating this project into other offices that would be our customers would require for our electronic systems to be robust enough to withstand any tampering, overcurrents, etc.
- Also, the form factor and pricing could be important, im guessing that we might want to move from hobbyists dev boards to a more granular solution (im thinking specific PCB's?)

Now, to be honest I don't want to have a full fledged 100% fail safe electronic's board before launching this as a product, since first we would like to test this with local markets, neighbouring offices or small buildings to which we can easily give support or replace parts in case something goes wrong. I would be comfortable to have a solution that moderately addresses these issues but that can be scalable.

Maybe then, if the project has success then we will be looking into creating this a mass production model but this is far away in my roadmap (~4 to 5 years in case its succesfull)

Now, back to the point, my question to you is, do you recommend any literature, have any advice as into how could we get this project working from a POC phase to a consumer product? Most of the resources I find on the net are either very "hobby" like (bare protoboards lying around the house) or really obscure. I just want to know what your suggestions are as far to a roadmap that I could follow so that I dont hit a wall moving from a phase to the next.

Thanks!

Comment: Some of the ideas behind fail faster don't work that well in hardware design because it is hard to do rapid design spins on mechanical parts in particular. It is better to have a series of discrete builds planned ahead of time with sufficient time in between builds to do adequate testing. Otherwise you end up with a hodge-podge of incompatible parts that you are trying to connect together.

Answer (score 1):

My advice for you for moving from a POC to a real product is: Doing **a lot** of testing. Think of everything that could go wrong and setup some good test cases, also at different temperatures.